# Transfer value of one column to another column into a new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 relevant columns.

```
+-------------+---------------+   
| Bezeichnung | Artikelgruppe |
+-------------+---------------+ 
|     A       |       1       |
|     B       |       2       |     
|     C       |       3       |
|     D       |       4       |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I want to paste the value of Bezeichnung into a new column (new_col) for all values of the column Artikelgruppe that are equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using a number of methods. One of the method is:

```py
df['new_col']=df['Bezeichnung'][df['Artikelgruppe']==0]
```

This would result in a new column with the values of column *Bezeichnung* where values of column *Artikelgruppe* are 0 and the other values will be `NaN`. The NaN values could be easily replaced at any time of point.

```
+-------------+---------------+---------+   
| Bezeichnung | Artikelgruppe | new_col |
+-------------+---------------+---------+
|     A       |       1       |    NaN  |
|     B       |       2       |    NaN  |
|     C       |       0       |     C   |
|     D       |       4       |    Nan  |
+-------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this also possible with the lambda function? I tried to apply it but didn't work...

Comment: `df['new_col'] = df['b'][df['a'].apply(lambda x: True if x==0 else False)]`. This would solve the purpose

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!